# Netezza SP throwing 'unexpected transaction command' Error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, merge, upsert, netezza

I have an SP in Netezza to do UPSERTS between two tables by using a composite key .

It Compiles Correctly but then throws this error :

ERROR:  unexpected transaction command in exec_stmt_execsql() - not allowed in stored procedure

DECLARE USERINPUT ALIAS FOR $1;
......
BEGIN
DELETE FROM MAIN_TABLE 
        WHERE TMS_NETWORK_ID||TMS_PROGRAM_ID IN 
        (SELECT TMS_NETWORK_ID||TMS_PROGRAM_ID FROM T_F_SPLIT_PROG_SCHEDULE_STG) 
        AND RUN_ID = USERINPUT ;
INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE SELECT 
    
       FROM STAGING_TABLE 
            WHERE RUN_ID = USERINPUT AND DEL_FLAG = 0;

.....
END;

It seems i m trying something that isnt allowed in Netezza SP's , but i dont know what is causing the error. Please Help...??

Answer (score 0):

I saw your SP and noted few points -

1) You are deleting rows from your main table and then inserting from raw/staging table to main table, this is not advisable way from documents perspective because it causes a lot more processes in memory to delete and can cause "serialization error" if any parallel thread will try to insert/update any record in main table.

2) I found some errors in your query -

> DELETE FROM MAIN_TABLE WHERE **TMS_NETWORK_ID||TMS_PROGRAM_ID** IN 
>       (SELECT **TMS_NETWORK_ID||TMS_PROGRAM_ID** FROM T_F_SPLIT_PROG_SCHEDULE_STG) AND 
>       RUN_ID = USERINPUT

I guess you are using composite keys but the way you are selecting and trying to delete is wrong.